# Nullpointer exception on popBackStack

Tags: android, android-fragments

i am developing android application using fragments and sherlock action bar,
i am using the method

Blockquote

`getSherlockActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();`

for returning previous fragments.
Sometimes it run well,but sometime it gives `NULL POINTER` exception.
what will the solution ?

Comment: why you people forget to post your error log? post your error log.

Comment: Do you add your previous fragment into the stack?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that there's nothing left to pop. Try checking to see if it exists before popping.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if there is any fragment on your backstack before you try to pop it.

```
if( getSherlockActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0 )
    getSherlockActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

Answer (score 0):

popBackStack() will **not** cause NullPointerException. I've created a piece of code and called it several times in a row - when there is nothing to pop. It just leaves current fragment visible and does nothing.
I think the problem is not is in popBackStack method, however, I wasn't using ABS, just a regular android fragments API's.
Could you provide a piece of code? Maybe the problem is elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

If there is no backstack it will cause the null pointer, I have an onMenuItemClickListener() that catches this with the following:

```
if(navController.getPreviousBackStackEntry() != null) {
   navController.popBackStack();
}
```